# How to set up ItemTouchHelper with RoomDB?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-cardview

So i want to make a To-Do app. I want to make `CardView` added to `recyclerView` swipeable. I used `ItemTouchHelper` but it does't work. Here is my code

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val rotateOpen: Animation by lazy { AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
 R.anim.rotate_open_anim) }
private val rotateClose: Animation by lazy { AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
 R.anim.rotate_close_anim) }
private val fromBottom: Animation by lazy { AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
 R.anim.from_bottom_anim) }
private val toBottom: Animation by lazy { AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
 R.anim.to_bottom_anim) }

private var clicked = false

private var dialogView: View? = null

private lateinit var mTaskViewModel: TaskViewModel

private val adapter by lazy { TaskRecycleAdapter() }


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    add_btn?.setOnClickListener {
        onAddButtonClicked()
    }
    edit_btn?.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Edit Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    delete_btn?.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    add_task_btn.setOnClickListener {
        showDialog()
    }

    recycleTask.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycleTask.adapter = adapter
    mTaskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[TaskViewModel::class.java]
    mTaskViewModel.readAllData.observe(this) { user ->
        adapter.setData(user)
    }

    ItemTouchHelper(object: ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            mTaskViewModel.deleteFromDatabase(adapter.getTaskAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition))
        }

    })

}

private fun showDialog() {

    dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.task_add_dialog, null)

    val dialog = Dialog(this)

    val task = dialogView?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.taskAdd)
    val taskDescription = dialogView?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.taskDescriptionAdd)



    dialogView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_data_btn)?.setOnClickListener {

        if(task?.text?.isEmpty() == true || taskDescription?.text?.isEmpty() == true){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dodaj poprawne dane", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }else{
            val addTaskToDatabase = task?.text.toString()
            val addTaskDescToDatabase = taskDescription?.text.toString()
            val taskAddToDatabase = data(
                0,
                addTaskToDatabase,
                addTaskDescToDatabase
            )
            mTaskViewModel.addTask(taskAddToDatabase)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dodano!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    dialog.setContentView(dialogView!!)
    dialog.show()
}


private fun onAddButtonClicked() {

    setVisibility(clicked)
    setAnimation(clicked)

    clicked = !clicked
}


private fun setVisibility(clicked: Boolean) {
    if (!clicked){
        edit_btn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        delete_btn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        add_task_btn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else{
        edit_btn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        delete_btn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        add_task_btn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
}


private fun setAnimation(clicked: Boolean) {
    if(!clicked){
        add_btn.startAnimation(rotateOpen)
        edit_btn.startAnimation(fromBottom)
        delete_btn.startAnimation(fromBottom)
        add_task_btn.startAnimation(fromBottom)
    }else{
        add_btn.startAnimation(rotateClose)
        edit_btn.startAnimation(toBottom)
        delete_btn.startAnimation(toBottom)
        add_task_btn.startAnimation(toBottom)
     }
 }
```

}

TaskRecyclerAdapter.kt

```
class TaskRecycleAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskRecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var list = emptyList<data>()


    inner class MyViewHolder(binding: TaskHolderBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(TaskHolderBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = list[position]

        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.task).text = item.task
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.taskDescription).text = item.task_Details
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    fun setData(newList: List<data>) {
        val diffUtil = DiffUtil(list, newList )
        val diffResults = calculateDiff(diffUtil)
        list = newList
        diffResults.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    fun getTaskAt(position: Int): data {
        return list[position]
    }
}
```

Repository.kt

```
    package eu.tuto.wooftask.database

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

class Repository(private val addTaskDao: taskDao) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<data>> = addTaskDao.readAllData()

    suspend fun addTask(user: data){
        addTaskDao.addTask(user)
    }
    fun deleteFromDatabase(user: data){
        addTaskDao.deleteFromDatabase(user)
    }
}
```

TaskDao.kt

```
    package eu.tuto.wooftask.database

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface taskDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun addTask(user: data)

    @Query("Select * From task_table order by id asc")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<data>>

    @Delete
    fun deleteFromDatabase(user: data)
}
```